# How to use the column names already in text file in R

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table

Suppose I have a text file, data.txt, containing

```
A  B  C  D
1  2  3  4 
5  6  7  8
```

Using read.table, I get:

```
> d = read.table('data.txt')
> d
    V1  V2  V3 V4
1   A   B   C  D
2   1   2   3  4
3   5   6   7  8
```

How do I make it so that instead of `V1 V2 V3 V4` appearing, I get the column names that are in the text file? In other words, I would like to have this:

```
> d
    A   B   C  D
1   1   2   3  4
2   5   6   7  8
```

Comment: `read.table` has the `header` argument set to `FALSE` by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `d <- read.table('data.txt', header=T)`